# Removing duplicates in SQL based on column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to remove orphaned rows from a database.  Let's say I have this table t:

```
session | name | record_date | uniqueid
1       | a    | 2019-04-03  | 1x
2       | a    | 2019-09-19  | 1x
3       | b    | 2019-08-09  | zr
4       | c    | 2019-09-19  | ww
5       | d    | 2019-09-03  | yy
6       | d    | 2019-09-25  | rr
7       | e    | 2019-09-28  | dd
8       | e    | 2019-04-19  |
```

I'm trying to remove duplicate entries based on oldest record_date, while evaluating both name and uniqueid to ensure they're actual duplicates (not a duplicate just based on name). The catch for not simply evaluating based on uniqueid alone is that some rows have null value in for uniqueid.  So in my example table, I'd want to remove the first and last rows.

Comment: Is session 8 supposed to have `dd` as a `uniqueid`

Comment: No, that's the catch.  Some rows have null value for uniqueid.

Comment: Do you want a delete statement or simply select?

Comment: Also what if the null uniqueid's date is the max date for that name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `delete`:

```
delete from t
    where t.record_date < (select max(t2.record_date)
                           from t t2
                           where t2.name = t.name and
                                 t2.uniqueid = t.uniqueid
                          );
```

Note:  The above keeps only the most recent record for name/uniqueid pairs.

If you want the unique rows in a query, I would recommend:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.record_date = (select max(t2.record_date)
                       from t t2
                       where t2.name = t.name and
                             t2.uniqueid = t.uniqueid
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are finding `max()` and does not want to consider null uniqueid so use where for filter null values

```
name,max(record_date),uniqueid from table_name
where uniqueid is not null
group by name,uniqueid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - with aggregration and `group by` with where clause to filter out `null uniqueid`

```
select name,uniqueid,max(record_date)
from tablename
where uniqueid is not null
group by name,uniqueid
```